# Merged two lists and apply search filter on it using flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, search

I have two lists one is `static` that has *month_names* and another list is `dynamic` have *data* is comes **from API**.

###### Months Lists is static:

```
List monthName= ["july", "august","september", "october","november", "december","january","febuary","march","april","may","june"];
```

###### Data list is dynamic comes from API:

```
var updatedList= [
{
  "transGroup": 1,
  "transType": 0,
  "serviceTypeId": 0,
  "serviceDescription": "Opening Balance",
  "financialYear": "2022/2023",
  "july": 54818.34,
  "august": 54818.34,
  "september": 0,
  "october": 0,
  "november": 0,
  "december": 0,
  "january": 0,
  "febuary": 0,
  "march": 0,
  "april": 0,
  "may": 0,
  "june": 0
},
{
  "transGroup": 990,
  "transType": 0,
  "serviceTypeId": 0,
  "serviceDescription": "Closing Balance",
  "financialYear": "2022/2023",
  "july": 54818.34,
  "august": 54818.34,
  "september": 0,
  "october": 0,
  "november": 0,
  "december": 0,
  "january": 0,
  "febuary": 0,
  "march": 0,
  "april": 0,
  "may": 0,
  "june": 0
 }
];
```

***Note***: in above list `serviceDescription` sometimes has been change like `Opening Balance, Closing Balance, Total,Interval,Intrest`...etc.

I have create ***myData list model*** from [`json_to_dart`](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Then I apply the `logic below`

```
List data = [];
int? monthIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < updatedList.length; i++) {
      if (monthName[monthIndex] == "July") {
        data.add(updatedList[i].july.toString());
      } else if (monthName[monthIndex] == "August") {
        data.add(updatedList[i].august.toString());
      } //upto all 12 months
    }
```

It gives the result like *july data in july card widget* , *august data in august card widget* and so on.....

###### Widget:

```
return ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: updatedList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, childIndex) {
    return ListTile(
      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
        vertical: -4,
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      title: Text(
        updatedList[childIndex].serviceDescription.toString(),
        style: caption,
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        data[childIndex],
        style: dataTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

My **result display correctly** in my widgets but **I want to add search filter on both lists**

I have try to **merged above** two lists

```
var mergedLists = List.from(monthName)..addAll(updatedList);
print(mergedLists);
```

he gives me `below like result`:

```
[July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, Instance of 'UpdatedListModel ',Instance of 'UpdatedListModel ',Instance of 'UpdatedListModel ',....]
```

##### Search filter

```
  List results = [];
  List displayList = [];
 //search function
  void runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = monthName;
      displayList = monthName;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      setState(() {
        results = monthName.where((data) {
          return data.toLowerCase().contains(
                enteredKeyword.toLowerCase(),
              );
        }).toList();
        displayList = results;
        setState(() {});
      });
    }
  }
```

##### Main Listview Widget:

```
    ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: displayList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          displayList[index],
                          style: dataTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        apiData(index, transactionLists)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: data List contains only string?

Comment: @eamirho3ein which data?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I want to apply search filter on mergedList ,when I type month name or any value from updatedList model it can be search

Comment: could you add the part that you call that logic? the for loop I mean, where did you call that?

Comment: @eamirho3ein please check my GitHub [file](https://github.com/ravindra6596/provider_tut/blob/master/lib/new_file.txt) and also check your linkedin for result images

Comment: @eamirho3ein please check my file

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your data,First define new variable like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> finalData = [];
```

then define a function like this:

```
formatData() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.generate(
        monthName.length,
        (index) => {"month": monthName[index], "service": []});
    for (var item in updatedList) {
      for (var month in monthName) {
        int index = result.indexWhere((element) => element["month"] == month);
        (result[index]["service"] as List).add({
          "serviceDescription": item["serviceDescription"],
          "value": item[month]
        });
      }
    }

    setState(() {
       finalData = result;
    });
  }
```

and call it in `initState` like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    formatData();
  }
```

then use `finalData` to create your main listview that contain the cards and use `finalData's service` to create child listview. Also use it to do your search function like this:

```
void runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = finalData;
      displayList = finalData;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      setState(() {
        results = finalData.where((data) {
          return data["month"].toLowerCase().contains(
                enteredKeyword.toLowerCase(),
              );
        }).toList();
        displayList = results;
        setState(() {});
      });
    }
  }
```

and change your main list to this:

```
ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: displayList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          displayList[index]["month"],
                          style: dataTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        //apiData(index, displayList[index]["service"])
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

then in your inner listview try this:

```
return ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: displayList[index]["service"].length,// index here is the main listview index
  itemBuilder: (context, childIndex) {
    var services = displayList[index]["service"];// index here is the main listview index
    return ListTile(
      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
        vertical: -4,
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      title: Text(
        services[childIndex]["serviceDescription"].toString(),
        style: caption,
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        services[childIndex]["value"].toString(),
        style: dataTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Can't understand and how can I implement search filter have you check my github [file](https://github.com/ravindra6596/provider_tut/blob/master/lib/new_file.txt)

Comment: could you include the part that you search?

Comment: eamirho3ein  added, if you want apply search filter mergedList also Im not trying this

Comment: code you also add you main listview? the one that show cards.

Comment: I have added main listview that shows the card, check my git file also

Comment: in your formData function if I replaced updatedList to my **UpdatedListModel** `updatedList` it gives the error near `"serviceDescription": item["serviceDescription"],` the error is _The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'UpdatedListModel'._

Comment: eamirho3ein have you try my listview?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: so I am not call `apiData` function?

Comment: what is inside apiData?

Comment: I am confused about mainList and Inner list how can I pass it?

Comment: pass what? inner list is represent the list you call widget and the main list is last list you add to question

Comment: but `displayList[index]["service"].length` it gives the error _type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'_ I have try also `int.parse(displayList[index]["service"].length)` but same error

Comment: please have you solve this `int.parse(displayList[index]["service"].length)`

Comment: no, I don't know why you get that error,