# Unable to get substring in flutter and wrong string length

Tags: flutter, dart, substring

I am working on application to show mobile contact list with initials in a circle, but not getting initial character for some contact names.

In below code, first name is from mobile's contact list and second one I have typed from keyboard.
I am able to get correct length and also first character of the second name, but length for first name is double and also not able to get first character (it gives �).

```
print("".substring(0,1)); //�
print("".length); //12
  
print("Nagesh".substring(0,1)); //N
print("Nagesh".length); //6
```

Thankyou in advance for answering....

Comment: The issue can be your charset. It's because when I try `.split('')` in the first one, it returns � 12 times. I can't help, but you might focus on the charsets.

Comment: because of multi byte string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to use substring with unicode:

```
subOnCharecter({required String str, required int from, required int to}) {
    var runes = str.runes.toList();
    String result = '';
    for (var i = from; i < to; i++) {
      result = result + String.fromCharCode(runes[i]);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
print(subOnCharecter(str: "", from: 0, to: 2)); // 
print(subOnCharecter(str: "Nagesh", from: 0, to: 2)); // Na
```

you can use this function instead of default `substring`.

Comment: instead of calling ``str.runes.toList()`` within the loop, store in a variable and then access within the loop..

Comment: @eamirho3ein, have you look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74623408/13997210) question please try to give answer of question

Answer (score 1):

The strings look similar, but they consist of different unicode characters.

Character `U+1d67d` `""` is not the same as `U+004e` `"N"`.
You can use `str.runes.length` to get the number of unicode characters.

A detailed explanation why the string length is different can be found [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/19854#issuecomment-108442678)

example:

```dart
void main() {
  var mobileStr = "";
  var keyboardStr = "Nagesh";

  analyzeString(mobileStr);
  print("");
  analyzeString(keyboardStr);
}

void analyzeString(String s) {
  Runes runes = s.runes; // Unicode code-points of this string
  var unicodeChars = runes.map((r) => r.toRadixString(16)).toList();

  print("String: $s");
  print("String length: ${s.length}");
  print("Number of runes: ${runes.length}");
  print("unicode characters: ${unicodeChars.join(" ")}");
}

// OUTPUT
// String: 
// String length: 12
// Number of runes: 6
// unicode characters: 1d67d 1d68a 1d690 1d68e 1d69c 1d691

// String: Nagesh
// String length: 6
// Number of runes: 6
// unicode characters: 4e 61 67 65 73 68
```